# Two flex slider in one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexslider

I have two flex slider in one page. I need to they two slider work separate. How do that ?

```
<section class="slider">
  <div id="frist-slider" class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li><img src="img-1.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img src="img-2.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-navigation">
    <div class="custom-controls-container"></div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="slider">
  <div id="second-slider" class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li><img src="img-1.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img src="img-2.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-navigation">
    <div class="custom-controls-container"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I use default flex slider java script for this code.

Answer (score 2):

You could set different options for each flexslider like so:

$('#frist-slider').flexslider({
        options: xyz,....
      });

$('#second-slider').flexslider({
        options: xyz,....
      });

Possible duplicate of:

[How to set up multiple sliders with flexslider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559209/how-to-set-up-multiple-sliders-with-flexslider)